# firestore subdocument update field

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I want to update a subdocument field (`appointmentdate`) in android java.

How can I do it using a `recyclerviewadapter`?

```
Collection    documentID     Collection   documentID
Member           -abc123-       Appointment - xyz123     Fields..  
                                                      appointmentdate
```

Comment: Can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55980966/edit) to show what you've tried already?

Comment: Please add to your question, what Frank van Puffelen asked for.